# The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[image]I simply want to save Date of Birth into SQL database, but every time getting new exception, database field type is datetime.
here is my code

```
 usinfo.BirthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what is your date format enterd in `txtDob` control?

Comment: i add date like '31/04/2012'

Comment: use this format `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: When you want to show date in text box from Databae..... use below formate                                                                                                                              txtEventDate.Text = DateTime.Parse(dr["EventDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Problem :** You are parsing the `Month` first using `MM/dd/yyyy`,
but you are giving `date` first like this `31/04/2012`

**Solution :** You need to use `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Try This:

```
usinfo.BirthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**EDIT:** You entered an invalid `Date` here: `31/04/2012`.

The month `April` does not have `31` days. It has 30 days. So you need to make sure you enter a valid date.

Comment: sorry it still showing the same error :( Is there to make any changes in WebConfig?

Comment: @Ayaat: can you debug your application and see what is the exact value of `txtDob` control?

Comment: @Ayaat: check my edited answer, april month can not have 31 days choose some valid date